# Centralised swagger for multiple drop wizard services

Tags: swagger, dropwizard

I've included swagger bundle in each of my dropwizard service. I was wondering if we can run swagger independently and connect to each service so that user can have a centralised view of all services through one UI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of something that lets you do that at the moment with Swagger UI specifically, but you might check out [DynamicApis.com](https://www.DynamicApis.com).  They let you host multiple swagger documents and provide some really nice additional value for your APIs as well.  They take your Swagger JSON and build you your own API portal out of them. They also have native REST API integration where you can automatically sync up your API to your portal or you can manually upload them.

[Here](https://www.dynamicapis.com/dapi) is an example portal they have up to demonstrate how multiple APIs can be hosted and how you see them.

[Here](https://www.dynamicapis.com/dapi/apis/0b971e55-c61f-4428-a65f-ca905bd52762) is an example of what their documentation for each API looks like. Kind of like Swagger UI++.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* have multiple swagger instances in a single DW service.  The UI, however, does not allow you to point to each of them independently.  It's easy enough though to modify index.html to allow the user to select the swagger definitions that you have in the deployment.